# Test for significant differences between groups (in R)

Tags: r, statistical-significance, t-test, group-differences

I want to assess whether the differences I find for different groups (of a factor variable) are significantly different from each other. Let's keep it hypothetical and assume a data structure like that:

```
Value     Group     A_binary     B_binary     C_binary
9         A         1            0            0
5         A         1            0            0
7         A         1            0            0
4         B         0            1            0
3         B         0            1            0
1         C         0            0            1
```

Now the underlying question is: "Does group affiliation affect the value in a significant way; that is, are the means found for A, B, C significant from each other?".

Now I probably run a t-test to see whether the mean "value" for one group differs from the one of another and so forth. I'd have to do this for every pair: A and B, B and C, A and C.

I'm wondering whether there's a neat, easy and fast way to do this in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Analysis of variance

If you want to obtain just a single global p-value then this would simply be a one-way analysis of variance (ANOVA). This can be carried out in a number of ways in R including:

```
oneway.test(Sepal.Width ~ Species, data = iris, var.equal = TRUE)
##  One-way analysis of means
## 
## data:  Sepal.Width and Species
## F = 49.16, num df = 2, denom df = 147, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

or

```
m <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Species, data = iris)
summary(m)
## [...]
## F-statistic: 49.16 on 2 and 147 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

But there are many other routes to obtain this test or variations of it, e.g., adjusting for heteroscedasticity etc.

#### Pairwise t-tests

If you want to conduct all pairwise t-tests then this is a multiple testing problem and the corresponding p-values should be adjusted for that. The `pairwise.t.test()` function in base R has a number of methods for this, defaulting to Holm's.

```
pairwise.t.test(iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Species)
##  Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 
## 
## data:  iris$Sepal.Width and iris$Species 
## 
##            setosa  versicolor
## versicolor < 2e-16 -         
## virginica  9.1e-10 0.0031    
## 
## P value adjustment method: holm
```

A more general approach would be to consider this as a set of linear hypothesis tests in a linear model, using Tukey contrasts. This can be done carried out in package `multcomp` supporting both the global test (ANOVA), the adjusted pairwise t-tests, and a number of further adjustment methods:

```
library("multcomp")
g <- glht(m, linfct = mcp(Species = "Tukey"))
summary(g, test = adjusted("holm"))
##   Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
## 
## Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts
## 
## Fit: lm(formula = Sepal.Width ~ Species, data = iris)
## 
## Linear Hypotheses:
##                             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
## versicolor - setosa == 0    -0.65800    0.06794  -9.685  < 2e-16 ***
## virginica - setosa == 0     -0.45400    0.06794  -6.683 9.08e-10 ***
## virginica - versicolor == 0  0.20400    0.06794   3.003  0.00315 ** 
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## (Adjusted p values reported -- holm method)
## 
summary(g, test = Ftest())
##   General Linear Hypotheses
## 
## Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts
## 
## Linear Hypotheses:
##                             Estimate
## versicolor - setosa == 0      -0.658
## virginica - setosa == 0       -0.454
## virginica - versicolor == 0    0.204
## 
## Global Test:
##       F DF1 DF2    Pr(>F)
## 1 49.16   2 147 4.492e-17
```

Comment: (+1) I think the post-hoc tests section would be better placed under the ANOVA heading.

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense. Quick question abou the `pairwise.t.test()` output though: what does the "-" sign tell me in this case? Highest significance of p<0.000? Or the opposite?

Also, I was wondering if I could simply run a linear model like that on my (hypothetical) data:
`summary(lm(testdat$Value ~ testdat$Group))`

This would make Group_A my reference category to which I can then compare the other groups. In this case we would see that group C is significantly different from A (alpha = 5%), but this is not the case for group B.

Does that make sense?

Comment: @FabianHabersack (1) The `-` signals that the corresponding pair is not tested (for versicolor vs. versicolor there is nothing to test). (2) Never use `lm(testdat$Value ~ testdat$Group)`, use `lm(Value ~ Group, data = testdat)` instead. (3) Instead of all pairwise tests (= Tukey contrasts) you can also use all against one (= Dunnett contrasts). The uncorrected tests are reported by `summary(m)`. For multiple testing adjustment `summary()` for `glht(m, linfct = mcp(Species = "Dunnett"))` can be used.

Comment: @mkt Most of these tests can be understood as either post-hoc tests or ANOVAs or "normal" significance tests. There are sometimes subtle differences wrt variance estimation, finite-sample or degrees-of-freedom correction, conditional vs. unconditional justifications etc. But for the examples chosen in my answer, the test statistics and p-values from the different views coincide exactly.

Comment: @AchimZeileis Fair enough, it wasn't an objection (hence the +1), more of an organisational suggestion.

Comment: @mkt Sure, fair enough! The feedback is appreciated. I was just pointing out that different organizations are more natural from different views. Maybe the headers should be omitted altogether?

Comment: @AchimZeileis I don't know - probably doesn't matter too much either way.